# Apple Wireless Keyboard on Windows PC - How to make FN and Eject keys work?

Tags: keyboard, windows

I have *Apple Wireless Keyboard (A1255, from 2007, US English layout)* and I want to use it on *non-Apple, Windows PC*. But I have two problems.

**Firstly**, Windows does not detect when "fn" and "eject" is pressed on.
**Secondly** - I want to rebind/swap these keys: "fn" to "control" (and "left control" to "fn") and "eject" to "delete".
I installed BootCamp on my machine but it has not changed anything.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [WinAppleKey](https://github.com/samartzidis/WinAppleKey/tree/master/WinAppleKey) only supports A1644.  Support for A1314 was removed in February 2019 so what are you after?  A similar (unsigned) kernel driver for A1255?  I have an A1314 and none of the old XP era autokey suggestions work with Windows 10.

Comment: Yup, I am looking for driver (not necessarily at the kernel level) that would add on my Windows 10 PC support for "fn", and "eject" key (i want to rebind "eject" to "delete").

Answer (score 0):

There is another open source software that works with my A1314 apple keyboard on windows 10.

Try it : [Apple Wireless Keyboard](https://uxsoft.cz/projects/applewirelesskeyboard/)

Remember to select restart from tray icon after configuration change.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better/more complete than the others already provided.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: This is on GitHub now: https://github.com/uxsoft/AppleWirelessKeyboard

Comment: it doesn't seem to work on the A1255 (I have the same problem) and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a little open-source project for this: [Bluetooth HID Hub](https://github.com/ruundii/bthidhub). It runs on Raspberry Pi Zero W (~$10/£10).

It is similar to RaspiKey, but:

- Supports not only a keyboard but a mouse as well, both wired or wireless
- Does not require a wired connection to your computer
- Supports connection to multiple computers (work on 2+ machines with the same keyboard Python based, so really easy to extend with your custom remappings or any other device-specific logic

Comment: That sounds like a neat little utility.  But, how does it remap the Fn key and Eject key?